# ruby1.9.2 install from source -> installation heisenbug

Tags: ruby, installation

I wanted to install ruby1.9.2 from source, and as the README suggested I ran `make test`.

At first run it failed with this:

```
sample/test.rb:gc ....not ok system 9 -- /home/user/Downloads/ruby-1.9.2-p136/sample/test.rb:1950:in `<main>'
not ok/test: 900 failed 1
test failed
```

Then I ran it second time, now test.rb:gc passed, but failed here:

```
sample/test.rb:system ........unknown encoding name: euc-jp
/home/user/Downloads/ruby-1.9.2-p136/ext/tk/sample/demos-jp/anilabel.rb
unknown encoding name: euc-jp
/home/user/Downloads/ruby-1.9.2-p136/ext/tk/sample/demos-jp/aniwave.rb
unknown encoding name: euc-jp
/home/user/Downloads/ruby-1.9.2-p136/ext/tk/sample/demos-jp/arrow.rb
unknown encoding name: euc-jp
/home/user/Downloads/ruby-1.9.2-p136/ext/tk/sample/demos-jp/bind.rb
unknown encoding name: euc-jp
/home/user/Downloads/ruby-1.9.2-p136/ext/tk/sample/demos-jp/bitmap.rb
.....and a lot more
```

For the third time, the previous errors didn't show up, but this:

```
test_autoload.rb ........bootstraptest.tmp.rb:4:in `block in <main>': undefined method `ok' for ZZZ:Class (NoMethodError)
.
.
.
#11 test_autoload.rb:54:in `<top (required)>': 
     open("zzz.rb", "w") {|f| f.puts "class ZZZ; def self.ok;:ok;end;end"}
     autoload :ZZZ, "./zzz.rb"
     t1 = Thread.new {ZZZ.ok}
     t2 = Thread.new {ZZZ.ok}
     [t1.value, t2.value].join
  #=> "" (expected "okok")  
FAIL 1/934 tests failed
make: *** [yes-btest-ruby] Error 1
```

Seeing the installation gradually 'heal', I continued running `make test`, and for the 6th time:

```
PASS all 934 tests
```

I'm on a Virtualboxed Ubuntu 10.10.

Does anyone know what is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming you ran configure then ran make. I am also presuming you have Bison or something similar installed. The last edge build I did was 1.9.2p94 since somewhere in their they fixed a bug with TCPSocket compared to 1.9.2p0

If you missed one of the above steps, I would guess that `make test` is building the dependencies for the test one at a time slowly getting further before needing to build more dependencies.

Comment: I don't have Bison installed, and yes I ran `.configure`, but just once, before running `make test`

Comment: `make test` is to test your build. If you don't have Bison installed I don't know how you actually built the project. After you `./configure` you should run `make -j 4` where -j 4 is 4 threads. *after* you have made the project you should `make test`

Comment: I meant I didn't install Bison manually, it is possible that it is installed by other automatism. I don't have much experience building software from source (especially correcting compile errors), but what's the logic make-ing the project first and then testing it?

Comment: Its kind of like learning the material first in school then getting a test on it. What you did is what I often did. Learned on the test.

Basically you test that your build is compliant.